# Can we use Cufon in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, css, adobe, dreamweaver, cufon

Just wanted to know if I can use Cufon in Dreamweaver via plugin or something ? or will I have  to insert the code manually ?

Regrads,
Netguy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Cufon is just a text replacement mechanism with javascript, you'll have to include it in your document manually. If you just want to see how your site will look with that font, you could put it in your font directory and include it in the fontlist of dreamweaver so you can see how it will appear as you work. Of course, this means you need to have the font locally and it will only work for you.

Comment: So there's no plugin.. Thanks a lot for the reply !